# How to find key given Vigenere Ciphertext?

Tags: encryption, vigenere

I can't seem to find a tutorial online that helps me with this tasking. I have some Vigenere ciphertext (LVGPA...). It only says to assume that encrypting the key letter A results in no change, B results in an increment of one, C increments 2, and so forth.

How would I start to find the key?

Comment: See http://crypto.interactive-maths.com/kasiski-analysis-breaking-the-code.html